# jQuery Trigger Click not work at first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a trouble with jquery trigger click. I need to play audio from audio tag via trigger click. When i click first time on first element it work, but if I click in another element, the first click not work. If i click 2nd time it will be work.

```
  var Audioplaying = false;
  jQuery('.playAudio').click(function(e) {

        var playerID = jQuery(this).next('.audioPlayer').attr('id');
        var playerBTN = jQuery(this);

        if (Audioplaying == false) {
            Audioplaying = true;
            jQuery("#"+playerID)[0].play();
            playerBTN.addClass('play');
        } else {
            Audioplaying = false;
            jQuery("#"+playerID)[0].pause();
            playerBTN.removeClass('play');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: well the Boolean is tied to what you click globally, so do you need the boolean tied to what you click?

Comment: try to add this in document ready: ```$(document).ready(() => { **YOUR_CODE** })```

Comment: _"if I click another element, the first click won't work"_ What do you mean? If you had already clicked and it worked, how can it possibly go back in time?

Comment: You are sharing the same `Audioplaying` variable for all the `playAudio` elements. So, it changes it to true in first click and when you click on any other `playAudio` element then since the value of `Audioplaying` is true it will change to `false` first and on second click it work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `Audioplaying` is shared, it is not unique so you probably want it to be unique per element. So use `data()` to keep track of the state for each player.

```
jQuery('.playAudio').click(function(e) {

    var player = jQuery(this).next('.audioPlayer');
    var playerID = player.attr('id');
    var playerState = player.data('isPlaying') || false; // get if it is running
    player.data('isPlaying', !playerState);  // update the boolean
    var playerBTN = jQuery(this);

    if (!playerState) {
        jQuery("#"+playerID)[0].play();
        playerBTN.addClass('play');
    } else {
        jQuery("#"+playerID)[0].pause();
        playerBTN.removeClass('play');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Why you don't use `$`, but `jQuery`?

Answer (score 0):

Maintain the state of each button separately. so, you can use an object with it's 'id' as the key.

example : { button_id : true/false }

```
  var Audioplaying = {};
  jQuery('.playAudio').click(function(e) {

        var playerID = jQuery(this).next('.audioPlayer').attr('id');
        var playerBTN = jQuery(this);

        if (!Audioplaying[playerID]) {
            Audioplaying[playerID] = true; // every button has it's own state maintained in the object.
            jQuery("#"+playerID)[0].play();
            playerBTN.addClass('play');
        } else {
            Audioplaying[playerID] = false;
            jQuery("#"+playerID)[0].pause();
            playerBTN.removeClass('play');
        }
        e.preventDefault();

  });
```

Hope it helps you arrive at a optimal solution.